# to plot a line on the median and mean points marked in a boxplot

Tags: python

I am having problem in plotting line on the median and mean points in a box plot. I tries several methods.Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statistics
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
a=pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
b=a['HH'][0:744].values
c=a['BC880'][0:744].values
d=[]
f=[]
k=[]
z=[]
x=list(range(24))
fig=plt.figure()
i=0
j=0
for j in range(0,24):
   for i in range(0,744):    
           if j==b[i]:
               d.append(c[i])         
   d=[d for d in d if str(d)!='nan']
   m=np.average(d)
   s=statistics.stdev(d)
   f.append(d)
   B=plt.boxplot(f,showfliers=False,showmeans=True,whis=[5,95])
   res = {key : [v.get_data() for v in value] for key, value in B.items()}
   t=res.get('medians')
   u=res.get('means')
   k.append(m)
   z.append(s)
   d=[]  
print(f,'\n','Average values are ',k,'\n','Standard deviations are ',z)
plt.title('Variation of BC880 concentration in Dec2018')
plt.xlabel('Hours')
plt.ylabel('Concentration of BC880 in ngm^-3')
plt.savefig('BC880 Concentration wrt hours-boxplot')
fig.set_figheight(5)
fig.set_figwidth(10)
```

I tried accessing the mean and median values from box plot.But I am unable to do that.Kindly help.

Comment: why don't you compute the mean and the median directly using numpy?

Comment: I was asked to connect the mean and median points that was on the box plot.So  I tried them by importing seaborne,it didn't work.That's why I tried accessing values from box plot rather than using numpy.